# Powerpoint animations render with black colors on macbook pro m1 2020

Tags: macos, ms-office, apple-silicon

I am at wits end as to how to fix this issue with microsoft powerpoint.

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- Powerpoint for Mac - Version 16.55

I am a teaching staff, and sometimes I need to present my slides along with some other apps on zoom. I've been able to do this seamlessly using a dual monitor. The presentations that used to work have recently started rendering a black screen such as this:
[image: black screen]
The issue happens when I toggle between another app and the powerpoint presentation.

I thought it may have been because of Monterey, but I reinstalled Big Sur and I am still facing the same issue.

Can anyone guide me in a fix for this type of error?